# Is the function $f( x)=1/|x|^{1/2}$ Lipschitz continuous?

Tags: continuity

Is the function $f( x)=1/|x|^{1/2}$ Lipschitz continuous near $0$? If yes, find a constant for some interval containing $0$

I  think the answer is yes since I can find $L=1$ that satisfies Lipschitz continuity criteria in a interval close to zero,am I right?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 1):

At zero the function $f(x)$ is not Lipschitz continuous any more, it is not even simply continuous. Close to zero - yes, but not in zero.

For every constant $C$ you can find $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)| > C|x_1-x_2|$. For example if $C > 1$ you can take $x_1 = \frac{1}{C}$ and $x_2 = \frac{1}{2C}$.

Comment: The stated $x_i$ don't work; eg if C = 1+e for small positive e,  $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)| < C|x_1-x_2|$.  However,  $x_1 = \frac{1}{C^2}$ and $x_2 = \frac{1}{2C^2}$ work.

Answer (score 0):

For any interval $[a,b]$ which doesn't contain $0$, function $f$ is Lipschitz and the constant $L = \max\limits_{[a,b]}|f'(x)|$.

For any interval $[a,b]$ which contain $0$, function $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: My function is different, I'm sorry for the typo!

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ is NOT Lipschitz continuous in any interval containing zero as $f(x)$ is not even defined at zero so it is not even continuous in the interval.

Comment: My function is different, I'm sorry for the typo.