# Lipschitz continuity power type function

Tags: functions, continuity

Is the function $f(x)=x^{\gamma+1}$, where  $x>0 $ and $\gamma<0$ Lipschitz continuous ? I am a bit confused !

Comment: Have you tried to solve this with some examples of specific values of $\gamma$, like say $-\frac12$?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723821/prove-that-if-f-is-derivable-on-a-b-and-f-is-lipschitz-continuos-then-f, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214511/is-the-function-fx-x1-2-lipschitz-continuous?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/214290/

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestions

Comment: is we let $x\in[\alpha,\bar{a}]$ where $\alpha>0$ then due to the fact that the derivative is bounded the function is Lipschitz. Is that correct?

Comment: peter5: On $[\alpha,\infty)$ with $\alpha>0$, $f(x)=x^p$ with $p\leq 1$ is Lipschitz, and yes, boundedness of the derivative implies this, thanks to the mean value theorem.

Comment: so, the problem if i got it right is around 0 ? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Yes.  You're welcome.